# Mrecord shapes orientations and rankdir

Tags: graphviz, dot

Is there any solution to not change the orientation of Mrecord shapes when the `rankdir` diagram attribute change ?

Here is a simple diagram example with the two outputs:

```
digraph g { 
  rankdir=LR // or rankdir=TB

  node [shape=Mrecord]

  1 [label="{<in1>In[1]}|Node[1]|{<out2>Out[2]|<out3>Out[3]}"]
  2 [label="{<in1>In[1]}|Node[2]|{<out2>Out[2]|<out3>Out[3]}"]

  1:out3 -> 2:in1
}
```

Output with `rankdir=LR`:

[image: LR]

Output with `rankdir=TB`:

[image: TB]

I would like to have a `rankdir=LR` for the diagram, but with Mrecord shapes aspect as in the TB diagram... How can I do that ? With subgraph ? Or maybe with HTML-Like Labels (but they are more complex to use) ?

Other related question: [record nodes and rankdir in graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259415/record-nodes-and-rankdir-in-graphviz)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/20184005/938081, Putting `{}` around the label text will change the direction of the Mrecord separators. Example:

`2 [label="{{<in1>In[1]}|Node[2]|{<out2>Out[2]|<out3>Out[3]}}"]`

The result is the following (same code as previous post):

[image: Mrecord]